# How to write deduction tree? Did my teacher did a mistake?

Tags: logic

By constructing deduction tree we have to show that:

$(p\rightarrow r),(q\leftrightarrow s),(r\leftrightarrow q), p\vdash s$

#### I.What the teacher tried

the teacher wrote:

$1. p\rightarrow r$

$2. p\leftrightarrow s$ (I think he did a mistake here)

$3. r\leftrightarrow q$

$4. p$

$5. \neg s$

[image: graph from the prof]

at the first step we use the "$R \rightarrow 1$" relation

at the second step the "$R\leftrightarrow 3$" relation

at the last step the $R\leftrightarrow 2$" relation.

I think that the second hyptothesis $2. p\leftrightarrow s$ should be changed to $2. q\leftrightarrow s$ which change the whole tree...

#### II. what I tried on my own

$1. p\rightarrow r$

$2. q\leftrightarrow s$

$3. r\leftrightarrow q$

$4. p$

$5. \neg s$

[image: the deduction tree I tried to plot]

At the first step I used $R\leftrightarrow 2$

At the second step I used $ R\leftrightarrow 3$

At the third step I used $R\rightarrow 1$ which close all branches and shows that assuming $\neg s$ from the realtion above leads to a contradiction.

Comment: It is clear that he made a typo given the question, and that it should indeed be $q$ rather than $p$.

Comment: Yes, it's a clear typo.  It's an easy one to make.  Always watch your p's and q's.

Comment: @Aravind, I tried to correct it on my own, can you tell me if you think I understood how does deduction tree works?

Comment: @Graham Kemp I tried to correct it on my own, can you tell me if you think I understood how does deduction tree works?

Answer (score 0):

$(p\rightarrow r),(q\leftrightarrow s),(r\leftrightarrow q), p\vdash s$

The proof by natural deduction of this is as follows:

$\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1. & p\to r & \text{premise }1 
\\ 2. & q\leftrightarrow s & \text{premise }2
\\ 3. & r\leftrightarrow q & \text{premise }3
\\ 4. & p & \text{premise }4
\\ 5. & r & 1, 4, \text{conditional elimination (Modus Ponens)} 
\\ 6. & q & 3,5, \text{biconditional elimination} 
\\ 7. & s & 2,6, \text{biconditional elimination}
\\ &\Box
\end{array}$

Comment: actually, I asked for a deduction tree like this one: http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeandcritical.net%2Fimages%2Fprooftreeltrdisjunct.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeandcritical.net%2Fprooftools%2Ftechnical&h=271&w=343&tbnid=z1xwZ4ScUW5ryM%3A&docid=L5VH2ZFRHZ3lgM&ei=XNooVq6LHML3aP3hueAH&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=790&page=1&start=0&ndsp=16&ved=0CCYQrQMwAmoVChMIrqm1743WyAIVwjsaCh39cA58